# AngularJS — изолированный scope для параметра. В чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, веб-программирование

Подключаю изолирвоанный scope к вложенной директиве.
Как только подключаю его этим кодом:

```
scope: {
      testBind: '='
    },
```

значение переменной testBind перестает наследоваться.

Простой код на planker
https://embed.plnkr.co/kLhwu8/

В чем может быть ошибка? Как ее исправить?

Comment: [/ Developer Guide / Directives - Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это:

```
<div my-dir2 testBind="testBind"></div>
```

Заменить на:

```
<div my-dir2 test-bind="testBind"></div>
```